# How to get input component's submitted value in backing component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have made a composite component with a backing `UIInput`. It contains a number spinner. When the spinner is changed, the new value doesn't get sent to the backing component.

I have simplified the situation (a backing will seem unnecessary, however, the problem still occurs).

The `Sytem.out.println` highlights the problem.

Composite component:

```
<cc:interface componentType="periodInput" >
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="org.joda.time.Period" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <p:spinner id="count" min="0" binding="#{cc.countComponent}" converter="javax.faces.Integer" label="Every "/>
</cc:implementation>
```

Backing component:

```
@FacesComponent("periodInput")
public class PeriodBacking extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    private UIInput countComponent;
    // And getter & setter.

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        Period period = (Period) getValue();
        if(period == null) {
            period = Period.weeks(1).withPeriodType(PeriodType.weeks());
        }
        int count;
        count = period.get(period.getFieldTypes()[0]);
        countComponent.setValue(count);
        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSubmittedValue() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, Object newSubmittedValue) {
        // PROBLEM: Always prints out '1':
        System.out.println("Count: " + count); 
        int count = (Integer) countComponent.getValue();
        Period totalPeriod = new Period(0).withDays(count);
        return totalPeriod;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }
}
```

The composite component is used like so:

```
<custom:Period value="#{cc.attrs.trackedproduct.samplePeriod}" />
```

Where `trackedproduct` is present in a `@ViewScoped` bean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int count = (Integer) countComponent.getValue();
```

You should get the submitted value, not the model value. The model value has at that point (during the conversion/validation phase) not been updated by the submitted/converted/validated value yet.

```
int count = Integer.valueOf((String) countComponent.getSubmittedValue());
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your `getSubmittedValue()` and `getConvertedValue()` are not properly implemented. This should do:

```
@Override
public Object getSubmittedValue() {
    return countComponent.getSubmittedValue();
}

@Override
protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, Object newSubmittedValue) {
    int count = Integer.valueOf((String) newSubmittedValue);
    Period totalPeriod = new Period(0).withDays(count);
    return totalPeriod;
}
```

#### See also:

- [Composite component with multiple input components](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html) - contains an elaborate explanation of how to write such a backing component properly.